# How to draw heatmap with dendrogram using javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, heatmap, dendrogram

I am new in data visialization and d3 library. I have to draw a heatmap with dendrogram using javascript d3 library.

Please suggest some example and clarification regarding below fig:

[image: Fig 1]

Sample data is like:

```
row, col, value
TRBV-1, Ai-102, 5
TRBV-2, Ai-103, 6
TRBV-3, Ai-109, -8
..   .. ...
```

Update:
I have plotted a heatmap based on requirement like below. Now need to create dendrogram for horizontal and vertical clustering.

[image]

Comment: that is the heatmap data, where is the dendrogram data

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ialarmedalien, as per my question I was asking for a guide line about how to draw this kind of diagram in javascript using d3. If I have any code right now then I would have been asked specific technical question.

Comment: SO is for specific technical questions; your question is more suited to a google search.

Comment: @ialarmedalien, Thanks for your suggestion. By the time I tried and created a heat map based on the requirement. Now, I need to create a dendrogram for horizontal and vertical heatmap data. updated the question.